# how to iterate a column through for loop and get value pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

i have a dataframe and i want values of particular column to process further.how can i get values
in pyspark, my code

```
        for i in range(0,df.count()):
            
            df_year = df['year'][i]
            print(df_year)
```

i'm getting output like this

```
Column<b'year'>
Column<b'year'>
```

Here is my expected output

```
2015
2016
```

Comment: what do you want to do with those values?

Comment: those values are parameters for another function.

Comment: and what does that function do? you don't write a data frame code like traditional programming where you evaluate every statement and then pass the result to the next function. with Spark dataframe the more you do lazy evaluation is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in df.rdd.collect():
     print(row['year'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want year column,

```
for row in df.select("year").rdd.collect():
    print(row['year'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkContext
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
>>> sql = SQLContext(sc)
>>> df = sql.createDataFrame([(2015, 4), (2016, 5),(2017,6),(2018,7)], ["Year", "Month"])
>>> df.show()
+----+-----+
|Year|Month|
+----+-----+
|2015|    4|
|2016|    5|
|2017|    6|
|2018|    7|
+----+-----+
>>> [x.Year for x in df.select("Year").collect()]
[2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,df.count()):
    df_year=df.collect()[i][1]
    print(df_year)
```

Where 1 is index of column starting from zero.